# Please, blacklist the bugs tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-blocklist-request

Today, couple of hours prior, the [bugs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs) tag was feed to Trogdor our favorite... dinosaur? (I'm not sure what he *is*)

Well, through the span of some hours, appeared again, and raging, and was horrible, The Bridge entered in panic, people died... well, not really, but seems that this tag will be hard to remove of the system so maybe some blacklisting should be in place to prevent the tag from appearing (again).

Answer (score 2):

[bug](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) was already blacklisted. I extended the matching pattern to cover [bugs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs) as well.

Comment: Now let's be mindful of [tag:glitch], as it's a legitimate tag for an actual game, but I've seen it used as a replacement to [bug] on more than one occasion.

Comment: Rename glitch to glitch-game and blacklist glitch?